# Changing image back to original after it is changed on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to use jQuery to hover over an image while it changes the other. I have that part done, the part I don't understand is when I hover over the image and then move the mouse off of it, how do I get the original image to come back? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#04").hover(function(){
        $("#imgBig").attr("src", "imgLab10/04.jpg");
     });
});
```

Comment: You can do this with pure CSS, you don't even need jQuery. There is an answer that explains this.

Answer (score 2):

`.hover()` [accepts two callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), one for `hoverIn` and one for `hoverOut`.

So you could do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#04").hover(
        function(){
            $("#imgBig").attr("src", "imgLab10/04.jpg");
        },
        function() {
             $("#imgBig").attr("src", "oldImg.jpg");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of changing the img source because you can have lag or disconnect issues then your alternative image may now show.  This can also be done without jQuery altogether.

```css
.img-swap{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.img-swap .img-swap-alt{
  display: none;
}

.img-swap:hover .img-swap-alt{
  display: block;
}

.img-swap:hover .img-swap-def{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-swap">
<img class="img-swap-def" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg"/>
<img class="img-swap-alt" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-300-300-1.jpg" />
</div
```

Comment: This is a nice approach! It will incur an increased loading time though, so beware if you have large images and lots of instances to apply this to.

Comment: Agree on the approach using pure-CSS whenever possible, and that this method works for smallish numbers of instances where all resources are downloaded during page load. Leverage sprites where possible and simply manipulate via CSS. Highest x-device/x-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

The you have to use it like :

```
$( "#04" ).hover(
  function() {
    //When the mouse enter
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", "imgLab10/04.jpg");
  }, function() {
    //When the mouse out
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", "imgLab10/OriginalImage.jpg");
  }
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` because it will eventually become deprecated.

If you want to change the image back, you need to use `.mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#04").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#imgBig").prop("src", "imgLab10/04.jpg");
  });

  $("#04").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#imgBig").prop("src", "orignalPath");
  });
});
```

I think this makes the code easier to understand because you're explicitly coding for both events, but that's just my opinion and `.hover()` also works well.

Answer (score -2):

JQuery .hover() method takes two function parameters. One is onMouseover event and the second is onMouseout event.

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

> ```
> .hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)
>
> handlerIn
> Type: Function( Event eventObject )
> A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.
>
> handlerOut
> Type: Function( Event eventObject )
> A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.
> ```